# What are some good online photo challenges?

Tags: competitions

A great way to learn and find ideas.  Some of these also have mini-games such as post-processing challenges, which is a wonderful way to learn about the different creative ways you can post-process the same image, and what you like best. The smaller and tighter the community, the more likely you will get better and more in-depth critiques.

**Reason to be cautious:**

- Beware of scams. (These are typically
  of the form "Congratulations, your
  photo has won a prize! We're
  publishing a very expensive book of
  the prizewinning photos, would you
  like to order a copy?". Of course,
  every entrant has won a prize...)
- Watch out for the copyright clauses;
  by entering, you may be assigning all
  rights in your photo to whoever's
  running the competition.-

**Free:**

[gizmodo.com/tag/shooting-challenge](http://gizmodo.com/tag/shooting-challenge)

[dpchallenge.com](http://dpchallenge.com)

[dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com/challenges/)

[Photo Friday](http://www.photofriday.com/)

[photocamel.com](http://photocamel.com/forum/contests-challenges-assignments/)

[photoforum.com](http://photoforum.com)

[dailyshoot.com](http://dailyshoot.com)

[fredmiranda.com](http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/)

[fujimugs.com](http://fujimugs.com)

[pentaxforums.com](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/photo-sharing-galleries/)

[dgrin.com](http://dgrin.com/forumdisplay.php?f=7)

[PhotographyBB](http://www.photographybb.com/category/assignments/)

[About Photography](http://photography.about.com/)

[the mindful eye](http://www.tmelive.com/)

[Small Aperture](http://smallaperture.com/category/events/competitions/)

[reddit PictureChallenge](http://www.reddit.com/r/PictureChallenge/)

[streetphotographynowproject](http://streetphotographynowproject.wordpress.com/)

[Great Photo Race](http://www.greatphotorace.com/)

**Other sources:**

[twitter.com/dailyshoot](http://twitter.com/dailyshoot) - an archive of a daily social game that went for 690 days.

[Flickr groups](http://www.flickr.com/groups/)

[panachallenge.com](http://panachallenge.com) - targeted mainly to Panasonic users.

**Prizes**:

[Photography Competitions - Photo Contests - Photo Awards](http://www.photographycompetitions.net/)

[Photo Compete](http://www.photocompete.com/)

Comment: the link dailyshoot.com is currently unavailable ; )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use answers to rate and comment on each one.

Answer (score 9):

There's already a big list of suggestions in another answer, so I'll just add:

- Beware of scams. (These are typically of the form "Congratulations, your photo has won a prize! We're publishing a very expensive book of the prizewinning photos, would you like to order a copy?". Of course, *every* entrant has won a prize...)
- Watch out for the copyright clauses; by entering, you may be assigning all rights in your photo to whoever's running the competition.

Answer (score 5):

One of the biggest, I would think, is [DP Challenge](http://www.dpchallenge.com/index.php) which has open and member based challenges across all sorts of areas. You can sign up for free to enter into open challenges, but the member challenges are reserved for paying members.

The other big one is the [DP Review](http://www.dpreview.com/) challenges, again they span all sorts of areas and concepts. DP Review signup is free and challenges are open to all site members.

Both of them also have extensive archives that you can explore.

Answer (score 3):

I always try to take part in [PhotoFriday](http://www.photofriday.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Gizmodo has a weekly shooting challenge - http://gizmodo.com/tag/shooting-challenge

Answer (score 2):

- http://panachallenge.com -> targeted mainly to Panasonic users.
- http://twitter.com/dailyshoot -> Not so much a contest, but a socially enabled album

Answer (score 2):

Nobody seems to have mentioned [photo.net](http://www.photo.net) yet (though I'm not sure whether you'd consider their photo critique forum a "competition" or not -- but it's on the same general order as photosig, for one example).

Answer (score 2):

Added [dgrin.com](http://dgrin.com/forumdisplay.php?f=7)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about flickr groups. While the badges you get are worthless, it still is a good way to get critiques of your photos.

Answer (score 1):

In redbubble.com you have a lot of challenges! You can even win vouchers for printing photos. Check this:

http://www.redbubble.com/challenges/open

Answer (score 0):

Check out [www.photoscramble.com](http://www.photoscramble.com) lots of contests going on and you can even create one for free. There was one that is ending that has free tickets to WPPI photo trade show.