# what are some online photography competition

Tags: competitions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On-line photo challenges](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/on-line-photo-challenges)

Just wondering what are some online photography competitions ?

Comment: Community Wiki, perhaps?

Comment: Duplicate? http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/on-line-photo-challenges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a word of warning on online competitions, a lot of them are simply rights grabs, meaning they run the competition to simply get hundreds or thousands of photographs to use as they wish without paying for any rights or license fees :(  Most important thing is to **READ THE SMALL PRINT!!**

Personally I entered an online competition with Microsoft and did not read the small print, the image I entered did not win anything, however Microsoft did use it in an email that went out to every Hotmail user world-wide, so several million people.  I got no tag line, no recognition at all and no compensation ... in the small print Microsoft now own copyright on my image to use as when they wish, how they wish, in any media and at any time.

Some online competitions are good and fair, just not many, so READ THE SMALL PRINT before submitting any entries to any competitions if you care about both your copyright to your images and your moral rights on the images too.

Answer (score 2):

One that I know about is called [Share the Experience](http://www.sharetheexperience.org), it's a contest by the National Parks Service.

Answer (score 2):

[Digital Photography Review](http://www.dpreview.com/) has a very active set of [challenges](http://www.dpreview.com/challenges/) with the winners chosen by the participants and other site members.

Answer (score 2):

[DP Challenge](http://www.dpchallenge.com/) have regular competitions with a variety of topics to help you focus the type of picture you take.

Answer (score 2):

ePHOTOzine (http://www.ephotozine.com/) has at least 1 photography competition every month with some pretty good prizes such as photography gear.