# Tips for improve photography skills in android phone camera

Tags: photography-basics, cameraphones, android

**I am really interested in Photography**

but i don't have the money to buy a camera right now

i already started photography using my **android phone camera**

but i want to **improve** my photography skills

more like **shooting angle, environment management etc.**

**any suggestion** will be appreciated

Comment: Related: [What are your easiest photography beginner tips?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-your-easiest-photography-beginner-tips)

Comment: Related: [Why do breathtaking views turn into “boring” photos, and how can I do better?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48228/why-do-breathtaking-views-turn-into-boring-photos-and-how-can-i-do-better)

Comment: [How does one develop good photographic vision and style?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-does-one-develop-good-photographic-vision-and-style)

Comment: [Can anyone suggest books/resources on the artistic side of photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4804/can-anyone-suggest-books-resources-on-the-artistic-side-of-photography)